# External hard drive stops responding for 30+ seconds every once in a while

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have this [4TB external hard drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TKFEE8K), when I am writing to it, it stops responding every few minutes for 30+ seconds when I try to read from it at the same time.

Is this common? The drive is a NTFS drive mounted on ubuntu. Not sure if this happens on Windows, as windows doesn't even know that the drive exists when plugged in on the same computer (It doesn't even show up in Disk Management).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is classic bad sector symptom.

chkdsk /r c:

(or whatever drive letter it is)

The bad news is you have 4TB so it might take over night to complete.

Comment: This was happening, then I formatted the disk (twice, once as exfat, then again as ntfs), and it still is doing this... does that matter?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn  The basic behavior is no different for any file system.  Except if you had xfs it doesn't support bad sector handling, and you would have to change filesystems or live with it.